# Decrease one VolumeGroup, increase another

Tags: linux, lvm

Is it possible to decrease the vg_home and increase vg_root? I am running RHEL. I need to know the steps.

```
[root@web /]# uname -a
Linux web 2.6.32-131.4.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 10 10:54:26 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@web /]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

[root@web /]# df -kh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_web-lv_root
                       50G  7.8G   40G  17% /
tmpfs                 7.8G  384K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2             485M   79M  381M  18% /boot
/dev/sda1             200M  256K  200M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/vg_web-lv_home
                      755G  6.2G  711G   1% /home

[root@web /]# cat /etc/fstab 

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Sun Jul 10 14:37:44 2011
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_web-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=bc2a5e3c-d55a-4980-887a-695cb0e0dbe7 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=C024-19D6          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_web-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_web-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `lv_home` and `lv_root`, presumably, given that `vg_home` doesn't exist... This is why I loathe the RHEL installer; it does such idiotic things with both naming and space allocation.

What you'll need to do is:

1. Ensure nothing has any files open in `/home`, and that nothing will try and access any files in `/home` during the resizing operation.  This is best achieved by dropping into single user mode (`telinit 1`, unless RHEL's gone and switched to upstart or something in recent versions), but if you at least turn off the HTTP and SMTP services you're on a good start.
2. Unmount `/home` (`umount /home`)
3. Fsck the filesystem (`fsck /dev/vg_web/lv_home`)
4. Reduce the size of the filesystem on `lv_home` to something sensible (`resize2fs /dev/vg_web/lv_home 45G`)
5. Reduce the size of the LV to something sensible, but a bit larger than the filesystem (because it's easier to make the filesystem a bit bigger later, but chopping off the end of the filesystem by making the LV a bit too small is catastrophic: `lvresize -L50G vg_web/lv_home`)
6. Fsck again (`fsck /dev/vg_web/lv_home`)
7. Mount the filesystem again (`mount /home`)
8. Expand the filesystem back out to the size of the LV (`resize2fs /dev/vg_web/lv_home`)

And next time, don't trust what anaconda wants to do, and create the LVs yourself to the sizes that are appropriate for your system.

Comment: Yes I did the abbreviation I need to increase vg_web-lv_root and reduce vg_web-lv_home

Comment: Expand the filesystem back out to the size of the LV (resize2fs /dev/vg_web/lv_home)  you mean (/dev/mapper/vg_web-lv_root)

Comment: No, I did not.  Extending the root LV is a separate exercise involving the use of `lvextend` and `resize2fs`, which I've left as an exercise.